# LNK2019 error when trying to use Stanford external C++ libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, static-linking

I am new to C++ and trying to learn from online Stanford CS106B course.

In this course, people from Stanford have provided external C++ libraries (Link to which is given below).

I have downloaded this zip file and extracted the contents. The folder structure looks like this

```
D:.
├───doc
│   ├───HelloWorld2
│   ├───images
│   └───pictures
│       ├───ClassHierarchies
│       ├───GInteractorDiagrams
│       ├───GObjectDiagrams
│       └───HelloWorld
├───examples
│   ├───DrawDiagonals
│   ├───DrawLines
│   ├───DrawRectangles
│   ├───Flower
│   ├───GHelloWorld
│   ├───GraphicsExample
│   ├───HelloWorld
│   ├───PacMan
│   ├───Snowflake
│   ├───Stoplight
│   └───USFlag
│       └───images
├───include
│   └───private
├───java
│   ├───classes
│   ├───java
│   └───src
│       └───edu
│           └───stanford
│               └───cs
│                   └───java
│                       ├───graphics
│                       ├───spl
│                       └───tokenscanner
├───lib
├───obj
└───src
    └───tests
```

The `include` folder contains all the header file for the classes and functions and `lib` folder contains `*.lib` file used for static import of external library.

I tried importing external library in Visual Studio 2022 project by writing a dummy program shown below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include"simpio.h"

int main()
{
    int limit = getInteger("Enter exponent limit: ");
    std::cout << "Library import worked" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To include the external libraries, I followed the steps in the tutorial, who's link is given below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=ZYLKI8FxiD8

The settings for included files in my projects are shown in the pictures below

[image]

and

[image]

[image]

Even after doing all of this, when I build my project, I am getting following errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl getInteger(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?getInteger@@YAHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function main Project1    D:\to copy\C++\CS106B\trial_chapter\Project1\main.obj   1   
Warning LNK4272 library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' Project1    D:\to copy\C++\CS106B\cpplib\cpplib\lib\StanfordCPPLib.lib  1   
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  Project1    D:\to copy\C++\CS106B\trial_chapter\Project1\x64\Debug\Project1.exe 1
```

I tried reading solutions from existing stack overflow questions but that did not help as I do not understand what am I doing wrong.

Can someone please help me with this..

Stanford C++ Library link
https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/StanfordCPPLib/

Comment: Not sure where you got your binaries from but they're not compatible with your project, you're probably better off building them from the source code

Comment: *"library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'"* means that you have a 32-bit library in a 64-bit project. A mismatch.